# How can I find the best function that fits the following data

Tags: fitting

Am trying to find a function that could fit this data for bond breaking minimum path but so far haven't found one. I have previously fitted such data to Fourier series using NonlinearModelFit but had trouble fitting this one. I would greatly appreciate your help.

```
data1={{-4.238, 0.027},{-4.137, 0.394},{-3.95, 2.048},{-3.808, 4.175},{-3.69, 6.485},{-3.547, 10.003},{-3.444, 12.996},{-3.267, 19.061},{-3.128, 24.549},{-2.986, 30.771},{-2.873, 36.075},{-2.71, 44.056},{-2.545, 52.326},{-2.386, 60.124},{-2.231, 67.266},{-2.067, 74.144},{-1.902, 80.393},{-1.777, 84.856},{-1.615, 90.527},{-1.465, 95.936},{-1.332, 100.951},{-1.219, 105.414},{-1.111, 109.93},{-1.032, 113.396},{-0.943, 117.439},{-0.858, 121.535},{-0.788, 125.158},{-0.714, 129.201},{-0.654, 132.719},{-0.598, 136.159},{-0.494, 143.116},{-0.433, 147.422},{-0.395, 150.126},{-0.294, 157.136},{-0.226, 161.363},{-0.171, 164.278},{-0.108, 166.798},{0.02, 168.584},{0.144, 164.987},{0.191, 162.072},{0.251, 157.215},{0.312, 150.914},{0.372, 143.615},{0.49, 126.366},{0.525, 120.668},{0.569, 113.474},{0.62, 104.994},{0.68, 94.886},{0.724, 87.718},{0.79, 77.531},{0.834, 71.283},{0.888, 64.141},{0.967, 54.794},{1.024, 48.782},{1.08, 43.452},{1.147, 37.519},{1.22, 31.585},{1.306, 25.389},{1.372, 21.031},{1.465, 15.386},{1.576, 9.321},{1.673, 4.464},{1.784, -0.656},{1.91, -6.012},{2.052, -11.421},{2.211, -16.855},{2.372, -21.818},{2.542, -26.622},{2.715, -31.243},{2.949, -37.439},{3.086, -41.273},{3.296, -47.469},{3.457, -52.562},{3.772, -63.038},{3.888, -66.924},{4.103, -74.091},{4.257, -79.08}}
```

Here is my code

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data1,
  A + Μ Cos[x] + Ν Cos[2 x] + Ξ Cos[3 x] + Ο Sin[x] + Π Sin[2 x] + Ρ Sin[3 x] +  Σ Sin[4 x], 
  {{A, 150}, {Μ, 3}, {Ν, 1}, {Ξ, 1}, {Ο, 1}, {Π, 1}, {Ρ, 1}, {Σ, 1}}, x,
   ConfidenceLevel -> 0.99, MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> Automatic]
fitplot = 
 Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotMarkers -> O , PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Plot[Normal[fit], {x, -4, 4},
   AxesLabel -> {"Reaction Coordinate", 
     "Energy/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(kcalmol\), \(-1\)]\)"}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue], Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: data and fit]

```
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table from fit]

```
(*assigning the equation of the fitted parameters to a function V[x] *)
V[x_?NumericQ] := fit[x]
```

Comment: But why do you fit with Fourier series, is there any reason to expect a periodic function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, a better fit could be obtained if you increased the number of parameters (within reason! a model with too many parameters will fit *anything*). To make it easier to explore that, let's use indexed variables as the multiplicative factors and generate the model and parameter list automatically, as a function of the number of components $n$ we want to include:

```
With[{n = 5},
  fit = NonlinearModelFit[
    data1,
    Total[{Table[a[i] Cos[i omega x], {i, 0, n}], Table[b[i] Sin[i omega x], {i, 0, n}]}, 2],
    Flatten@{Array[a, n + 1, 0], Array[b, n], omega}, x, 
    Method -> "NMinimize"]
  ];

fit["ParameterTable"]

Plot[
  fit[x], {x, data1[[1, 1]], data1[[-1, 1]]},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Prolog -> {PointSize[0.01], Black, Point[data1]}
]
```

[image: table of parameters from the fit]

[image: plot of fit (line) and data (points)]

Comment: Very nice solution!  It is quite good with n=5 (as you show) and with n=7, the computed and points are nearly perfect.

Comment: @MarkR Yes the fit will get better and better the more parameters you introduce, until you have as many parameters as you have points, and then you will just be interpolating your function :-) Beware of overfitting!

Comment: thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 4):

In your "Fourieranalysis" it's necessary to include the frequency `ω` as an additional parameter!

Try

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
         data1, 
         A + Μ Cos[ω x] + Ν Cos[2 ω x] + Ξ Cos[3 ω x] + 
           Ο Sin[ω x] + Π Sin[2 ω x] + ΡSin[3 ω x] + Σ Sin[4 ω x],
         {A, Μ, Ν, Ξ, Ο, Π,Ρ, Σ, ω },
         x, Method -> "NMinimize"]

Show[{
  Plot[Normal[fit], {x, -data1[[1, 1]], data1[[-1, 1]]}], 
  ListPlot[data1]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plots with fit]

Comment: Rather than `Normal[fit]`, it may be more natural to use `fit[x]` inside the plot. Also, I am not sure that there should be a negative sign in `-data[[1, 1]]`: shouldn't that be just `data[[1, 1]]`?

Comment: @MarcoB Your are right ```Fit[x]``` look more natural here. For the ```Plot```, I just specified the range explicitly but in this case it should be just `data1[[1,1]]`

Comment: @ UIrich Neumann I had tried adding frequency but the fit wasn't that good. Here I just want an analytical expression which fits the data regardless of the form. I would use these expression in the `NIntegrate` to calculate several integrals along the energy axis as shown here

Comment: @fred85 The fit with frequency in MarcoB 's and my answer is quite good I think.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an extended comment to add to the approaches that @MarcoB and @UlrichNeumann provided.

To determine how many sets of cosine/sine terms are appropriate one needs a metric to judge the quality of the resulting model.  A common statistical metric is $AIC_c$ which is available from `NonlinearModelFit`. $AIC_c$ is a relative measure and allows you to rank competing models.  The model with the smallest $AIC_c$ value gives you the best of a collection of horrible or very good models.

An alternative approach is to use the root mean square error:  `fit["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5`.  This is an "absolute" measure which gives you the standard error of the prediction at the mean of the predictor values.  One uses their subject matter knowledge to decide on if a model's root mean square error is small enough.

For this dataset the following figures for $AIC_c$ and root mean square error can be generated:

```
results = {{2, 659.943, 16.5092}, {3, 599.761, 10.9489}, {4, 510.368, 5.99449},
   {5, 457.662, 4.15564}, {6, 357.128, 2.10662}, {7, 316.324, 1.56969},
   {8, 163.249, 0.562518}, {9, 128.91, 0.434393}, {10, 1.10447, 0.18216},
   {11, -5.198, 0.167454}, {12, -20.9262, 0.144134}, {13, -5.81008, 0.15079},
   {14, 57.7525, 0.214809}, {15, 32.834, 0.171122}, {16, 51.2808, 0.179277},
   {17, 33.2177, 0.146872}, {18, 68.3095, 0.168188}, {19, 134.711, 
    0.233195},
   {20, 110.034, 0.176447}};
ListPlot[results[[All, {1, 2}]], Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Number of terms", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(AIC\), \(c\)]\)"}]
ListPlot[results[[All, {1, 3}]], Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Number of terms", 
    "Root mean square error"}]
```

[image: AICc vs number of terms]

[image: Root mean square error vs number of terms]

So $AIC_c$ suggests that having 12 terms is the best of the models with 2 to 20 sets of terms and 12 terms also has the minimum root mean square error.

If one picked 12 terms based on those results, that would be doing so without any subject matter knowledge.  And that would seem nuts to me.

If a mean square error of 0.562518 associated with 8 terms is adequate for you, then based on your knowledge, that's what you should choose.  There is no law that says you need to choose the model with the miniminum $AIC_c$ or the minimum root mean square error.  While both of those statistics are good guides as to what your data supports, you need to use your subject matter knowledge to decide.  You need to choose an "adequate" model by your standards.

Comment: Thank you. AIC looks interesting and I will definitely read more about it. However, what am looking for is any analytical expression that fits the data. Such expression with be passed to an `NIntegrate`.

Comment: AIC simply ranks the models.  And then you pick the desired model.  AIC does not change the model in any way.  So you end up with an analytical expression as desired.  But note that some use AIC in a weighting scheme and "average" the models examined (called "model averaging").  I don't recommend that in this case.

Comment: I think it is really useful in evaluating the number of parameters one might need to effectively fit a certain model. I have fit the model proposed by @MarcoB with n=6 as you suggested and it fits very well. Thanks for mentioning it here.